Ariflow Tasks in TaskGroup run out of order
I'm using Dynamic Task Mapping feature with Task Groups to generate n number of tasks for my input list. DAG gets generated but at execution I'm seeing odd behaviour.

Mapped Tasks from second Task are getting triggered simultaneously when Mapped Tasks from first Task are still running. This is reflected in MWAA's logs:

This non-deterministic run causes DAG to fail.
Tried both depends_on_past=True, wait_for_downstream=True parameters to no luck. Kind thanks for any help...
DAG:
@dag(dag_id='chore_task_group_stage3', catchup=False)
def pipeline():

    # t0 = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    # t3 = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    @task_group(group_id="channel_demo_tg")
    def tg1(my_num):
        
        @task()
        def print_num(num):
            return num

        @task()
        def add_42(num):
            return num + 42

        print_num(my_num) >> add_42(my_num)

    # creating 6 mapped task group instances of the task group group1
    tg1_object = tg1.expand(my_num=[19, 23, 42, 8, 7, 108])

    # setting dependencies
    tg1_object

pipeline()

Scheduler log:
[[34m2024-08-05T14:11:19.118+0000[0m] {{[34mtask_context_logger.py:[0m91}} ERROR[0m - Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance: chore_task_group_stage3.group1.add_42 manual__2024-08-05T14:10:41+00:00 map_index=4 [queued]> finished (failed) although the task says it's queued. (Info: None) Was the task killed externally?[0m


Please provide a complete DAG definition as a Python code to check what may go wrong.

have you tried @task instead of @task() - I think with decorators the former is the right approach.

Same behaviour with @task

Weird. Which version are you using? I've done something similar, were I have a task followed by a sensor in the same group. It used to work. But I used the plain API (no decorator).

We use MWAA==2.8.1

Adding default_args={ "donot_pickle": "True" } in @dag parameters fixed the issue.
But when tasks are not in taskgroup, it doesn't work.
